# Spring form : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting following error while submitting my spring form

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
```

It seems like I am missing some parameters or with incorrect format while submitting the request, but I am not sure about which ones.

> My jsp is:

```html
<%@ include file="./inc/header.jsp"%>

<!-- form section-->
<section class="formSection">
 <div class="container">
  <h1 class="sectionHeading">Add review</h1>
  
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="postReview">
   <form id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
     <li class="active">Select categories</li>
     <li>Select Employees</li>
     <li>Post a Review</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <form:form modelAttribute="review" enctype="multipart/form-data"
     method="post">
     <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Select categories</h2>
      <c:forEach items="${serviceCategoriesList}" var="serviceCategory">
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 cateOption">
        <div class="cateDisp-icon">
         <img
          src="/getServiceCatImage/${serviceCategory.id}"
          alt="">
        </div>
        <p>${serviceCategory.serviceCatName}</p>


        <form:checkbox path="serviceCategories"
         id="${serviceCategory.id}" value="${serviceCategory.id}"
         class="chk_service_category" />
        <label for="${serviceCategory.id}">&nbsp; </label>
        <form:errors class="invalid" path="serviceCategories" />
       </div>
      </c:forEach>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button"
       value="Next" onclick="javascript:getCategoryEmployees();" />
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset id="fieldSetEmployees">
      <h2 class="fs-title">Select Employees</h2>

      
      <div id="empContainer"></div>
      
      <div class="clearfix"></div>

      <input type="button" name="previous"
       class="previous action-button ceter" value="Previous" /> <input
       type="button" name="next" class="next action-button center"
       value="Next" />
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Post a Review</h2>
      
      <div class="">
       <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <form:label path="customerFirstName">Customer First Name<em
          class="mandatory">*</em>
        </form:label>
        <form:input path="customerFirstName" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors class="invalid" path="customerFirstName" />

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <form:label path="customerLastName">Customer Last Name<em
          class="mandatory">*</em>
        </form:label>

        <form:input path="customerLastName" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors class="invalid" path="customerLastName" />

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="">
       <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <form:label path="jobID">Job ID<em
          class="mandatory">*</em>
        </form:label>

        <form:input path="jobID" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors class="invalid" path="jobID" />

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <form:label path="reviewTitle">Review Title<em
          class="mandatory">*</em>
        </form:label>

        <form:input path="reviewTitle" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors class="invalid" path="reviewTitle" />

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="">
       <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <form:label path="review">Review<em
          class="mandatory">*</em>
        </form:label>
        <form:textarea path="review" rows="5" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors class="invalid" path="review" />

       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="">

       <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <form:label path="starRating" class="left-block">Star Rating<em
          class="mandatory">*</em>
        </form:label>
        <input type="number" name="starRating.id" id="starRatingiD"
         class="rating" data-clearable="remove" />
        <form:errors class="invalid" path="starRating" />

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>


       <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

        <form:label path="reviewVideo" class="left-block">Upload Video Review</form:label>

        <input name="reviewVideo" type="file">
        <form:errors class="invalid" path="reviewVideo" />


        <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="">
       <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <form:label path="apprenticeReview">Apprentice Review<em
          class="mandatory">*</em>
        </form:label>
        <form:textarea path="apprenticeReview" rows="5"
         cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors class="invalid" path="apprenticeReview" />

       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <input type="button" name="previous"
       class="previous action-button center" value="Previous" /> <form:button type="submit" 
       class="orangebtn btn mtop20">Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right left"></i></form:button>
     </fieldset>
    </form:form>
   </form>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

 </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var arrCheckedCategories = "";
 function getCheckedCategories() {
  arrCheckedCategories = $('input:checkbox.chk_service_category').filter(
    ':checked').map(function() {
   return this.id;
  }).get();

  console.log(arrCheckedCategories);
 }
 function getCategoryEmployees() {
  getCheckedCategories();
  console.log("--" + arrCheckedCategories);
  console.log("url = " + contextPath
    + '/review/fetchemp?empType=Employees&catids='
    + arrCheckedCategories);

  $
    .ajax({
     type : "get",
     cache : false,
     url : contextPath
       + '/review/fetchemp?empType=Employee&catids='
       + arrCheckedCategories,
     success : function(response) {
      $("#empContainer").html("");
      //$('#result').html(data);
      var genHTML = "";//'<h2 class="fs-title">Select Employees</h2>';

      //var response = JSON.parse(response);

      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
       var obj = response[i];

       genHTML = genHTML
         + '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 cateOption">'
         + '<div class="cateDisp-icon">'
         + '<img src="/getEmpImage/'+obj['id'] +'" alt="">'
         + '</div>'
         + '<p>'
         + obj['empFirstName']
         + ' '
         + obj['empLastName']
         + '</p>'
         + '<input type="checkbox" name="employees" id="'+obj['id']+'" /><label for="'+obj['id']+'"/>&nbsp;</label></div>';
      }

      console.log("generated html is: " + genHTML);
      $("#empContainer").append(genHTML);

      console.log("url = " + contextPath
        + '/review/fetchemp?empType=Apprentice&catids='
        + arrCheckedCategories);

      $
        .ajax({
         type : "get",
         cache : false,
         url : contextPath
           + '/review/fetchemp?empType=Apprentice&catids='
           + arrCheckedCategories,
         success : function(response) {
          //$('#result').html(data);
          var genHTML1 = "";//'<h2 class="fs-title">Select Employees</h2>';

          //var response = JSON.parse(response);

          for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
           var obj = response[i];

           genHTML1 = genHTML1
             + '<div class="clearfix"></div><h2 class="fs-title">Select Apprentices</h2><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 cateOption">'
             + '<div class="cateDisp-icon">'
             + '<img src="/getEmpImage/'+obj['id'] +'" alt="">'
             + '</div>'
             + '<p>'
             + obj['empFirstName']
             + ' '
             + obj['empLastName']
             + '</p>'
             + '<input type="checkbox" name="apprentices" id="'+obj['id']+'" /><label for="'+obj['id']+'"/>&nbsp;</label></div>';

          }

          //  genHTML = genHTML + '<div class="clearfix"></div><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button ceter" value="Previous" /> <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button center" value="Next" />';

          console.log("generated html is: "
            + genHTML1);
          $("#empContainer").append(genHTML1);
         },
         error : function(e) {
          alert(e);
         }
        });

     },
     error : function(e) {
      alert(e);
     }
    });

 }
</script>

<!-- top review end -->


<%@ include file="./inc/footer.jsp"%>
```

> My controller is

```
/*
 * This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
 * saving review in database. It also validates the user input
 */

@RequestMapping(value = { "/add" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveReview(@Valid @ModelAttribute("review") Review review,
        BindingResult result, Model model, Map<String, Object> map,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    boolean isError = false;

    logger.debug("Entered saveReview method");
    logger.debug("review.getCustomerFirstName() : " + review.getCustomerFirstName());
    logger.debug("review.getCustomerLastName() : " + review.getCustomerLastName());
    logger.debug("review.getReview() : "
            + review.getReview());

    logger.debug("review.getReviewTitle() : " + review.getReviewTitle());
    logger.debug("review.getJobID() : " + review.getJobID());
    logger.debug("review.getServiceCategories() : "
            + review.getServiceCategories());
    logger.debug("review.getApprentices() : "
            + review.getApprentices());
    logger.debug("review.getEmployees() : "
            + review.getEmployees());
    logger.debug("review.getReviewVideo() : "
            + review.getReviewVideo());

    logger.debug("review.getStarRating() : "
            + review.getStarRating());
return "redirect:/";

}
```

While submitting the form from jsp the url which is displaying when the error is generated is:

```
http://localhost:8080/abc/review/add?serviceCategories=1&_serviceCategories=on&serviceCategories=2&_serviceCategories=on&_serviceCategories=on&_serviceCategories=on&_serviceCategories=on&_serviceCategories=on&_serviceCategories=on&_serviceCategories=on&_serviceCategories=on&_serviceCategories=on&employees=on&apprentices=on&customerFirstName=Cust1&customerLastName=Last1&jobID=123&reviewTitle=Review+Title1&review=xvxc&starRating.id=2&reviewVideo=Checkout.avi&apprenticeReview=xcvxvcvx&_csrf=47624284-af47-4b37-81ab-fd4216d7c918
```

---

Adding logs after enabling debug level for spring and application related logs.

```
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,147 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,150 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '18' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,151 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,154 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '17' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,151 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,159 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '20' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,151 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,167 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '19' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,174 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,177 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 18
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,191 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,216 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 19
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,217 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438565998421_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,188 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,219 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 20
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,221 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438730168480_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,185 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,215 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438565590343_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,224 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 17
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:15:57,226 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438563646726_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,673 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,954 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,955 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,955 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,954 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,954 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,960 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '15' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,959 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '1' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,958 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '4' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,957 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '2' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,956 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,975 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '16' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,956 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '3' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,976 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,973 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,968 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,966 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,986 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,985 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,985 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 4
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,985 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 2
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,983 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,989 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/icon-ref.png
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,989 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/icon-electrical.png
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,988 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 3
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,000 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/icon-plumbing.png
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,987 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/icon-heat.png
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,987 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 15
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,013 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,015 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '19' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,012 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,010 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,023 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '18' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:18,990 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 16
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,025 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438324717080_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,024 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,034 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 19
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,019 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,017 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '17' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,013 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-1] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438320334003_Untitled.png
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,036 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.dao.helper.ServiceCategoryDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE sc.deleted =  0 AND  sc.id = '20' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,035 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438565998421_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,032 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,047 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 18
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,048 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-6] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438565590343_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,056 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,067 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 17
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,068 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438563646726_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,068 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Service Category Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,071 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 20
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:19,072 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438730168480_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,396 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - selected employe type :Employee
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,397 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - selected categories are :1,2
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,399 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - selected categories id :1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,400 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - selected categories id :2
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,403 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): Employee Type
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,404 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): serviceCatIdList
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,405 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE e.deleted = 0 AND  e.employeeType.id = '1'  AND ( serviceCategories.id = '1'  OR  serviceCategories.id = '2'  )
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,424 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - employeeList.size() : 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,424 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - employee.getId() : 11
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,457 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - selected employe type :Apprentice
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,457 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - selected categories are :1,2
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,458 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,459 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - selected categories id :1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,459 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE (e.deleted = 0 OR e.deleted =  1) AND  e.id = '11' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,460 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - selected categories id :2
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,464 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): Employee Type
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,464 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): serviceCatIdList
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,465 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE e.deleted = 0 AND  e.employeeType.id = '2'  AND ( serviceCategories.id = '1'  OR  serviceCategories.id = '2'  )
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,478 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Employee List Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,478 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - employeeList.size() : 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,480 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.ReviewController  - employee.getId() : 10
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,479 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 11
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,482 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-5] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1439340240683_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,495 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - where Clause field.toString(): id
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,497 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.dao.helper.EmployeeDAOHelper  - queryString:  WHERE (e.deleted = 0 OR e.deleted =  1) AND  e.id = '10' 
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,511 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - Employee List Found: 1
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,512 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++id: 10
DEBUG   2015-08-13 12:16:23,513 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-2] com.abc.controller.HomeController  - +++++++++++rpath: G:/abc/Code/StorageSpace/1438927461554_4-gas-ducted-heating.jpg
```

Comment: Turn on your debug logs. Spring will tell you why and how the request is malformed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried debug logs. But I am not getting any debug logs for this error

Comment: Can you post the Spring logs you see? If you don't see any, you haven't enabled them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Added the logs

Comment: Maybe your HTML is not properly formatted?

Comment: @Sanjay Can you elaborate on that? I think it is properly formatted cause there is no formatting error that I can see in eclipse

Comment: The generated HTML which includes your include headers,footers etc, may be missing a closing tag or something. Just taking a guess.

Comment: Those are all your logs. I don't want your logs. I want to see Spring's logs for a single request-response cycle where you get a 400 status code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis where can I find the spring logs? I am using JBoss 7.1.1 and the only logs I am able to refer are "server.log", "boot.log" and the custom log in my file "servicecat.log". I am not able to see any spring related log for asingle request-response cycle where I get a 400 status code

Comment: I see. Look up how to configure Spring with slf4j and either logback or logj4(2).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I guess that is already there. I have added log4j.xml using web.xml and defined the configuration related to application and spring logging in log4j.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

In my jsp, I mistakenly had two forms (one under the other)

```
<form id="msform">
            <!-- progressbar -->
            <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active">Select categories</li>
                <li>Select Employees</li>
                <li>Post a Review</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- fieldsets -->
            <form:form modelAttribute="review" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                method="post">
```

I updated the code to following and now I am not getting this error

```
<form:form modelAttribute="review" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                    method="post" id="msform"> 
                <!-- progressbar -->
                <ul id="progressbar">
                    <li class="active">Select categories</li>
                    <li>Select Employees</li>
                    <li>Post a Review</li>
                </ul>
```